# Global.asax is a HttpHandler or HttpModule?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, global-asax, httpmodule

I was asked in a interview about Global.asax and its functionality,and then asked me what is regarded between the `HttpHandler` and `HttpModule`? i answered `HttpModule`, based on my understanding that HttpModule is in request pipeline and HttpHandler is responsible for generating response.

But when i looked at Global.asax base classes i saw that its inherited from `IHttpHandler` .

Why Global.asax should be regarded a handler while it is not Handling requests?

Answer (score 0):

Global.asax implements IHttpHandler (among other interfaces) but also derives from the base class HttpApplication, and yes it does handle requests as you can see from decompiling HttpApplication.

Comment: More detailed explanation please

Comment: "Why Global.asax should be regarded a handler while it is not Handling requests?" - because it implements IHttpHandler and also derives from HttpApplication, which should answer your question (which is wrong - it does handle requests)

Comment: But if you look at global.asax behavior it looks like HttpModule  not HttpHandler.